# Including files by relative path

Tags: php, path, include

There must be something i don't understand about linking files -- but here's my problem.

Basically, i have three files.

1. generalfunctions.php
2. wordcount.php
3. index.php

All three files are in different directories.

B relies on A as follows: `../../../phpfunctions/generalfucntions.php`
And when I run B all is well.

But C relies on B as follows: `../wordcount.php`

When I run C, I get an error saying that linked file A cannot be found.

The actual error is:

> No such file or directory in /.../public_html/plaoul/text/statistics/wordcount.php on line 11

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong??

Thanks for your help.

Comment: @Sinthia public_html/plaoul/text/statistics/wordcount.php

Comment: Thanks for the good question. It'd probably be easier to comprehend if there was an explicit mention of the site / file structure.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you use `include` to include a file, and you use a *relative path* as parameter, it will be **relative to the current working path**.

What is the current path? It is normally the path of the first called PHP script. The script where the whole execution started. You can get the current working dir with the function `getcwd`. For example: `<?php echo getcwd(); ?>` will show you the **current** working path. You can **change** the current working path using the `chdir` function. For example: `<?php chdir( '/home/myself' ); ?>` - with this command you just changed the current working path!

So, it is not always good to use **relative paths** in **include**, because the **current path** MAY change.

But with the usage of the `__FILE__` **magic constant** you can use a sort of *relative path* as a parameter for an include, making it **relative to the file where the include command is**. This is good! Because no matter what the **current working path** is, the include will be always relative to the file which is including!

So... try the following:

In B you should include A as follows:

```
include( dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/../../../phpfunctions/generalfunctions.php' );
```

In C you should include B as follows:

```
include( dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/../wordcount.php' );
```

In short: using `dirname( __FILE__ )` you can include the file using a path relative to the file where the "include" command is. Otherwise, the path will be relative to the current working path.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what `___FILE___` -- I'm not actually supposed to right `__File__` am I?

Comment: @Jeff: It is `__FILE__`, not `___FILE___`. Yes, you are actually supposed to write `__FILE__` (two underscores before and after, capital letters): http://php.net/manual/en/language.constants.predefined.php

Comment: From PHP 5.3.0 onwards, you can use `__DIR__` instead of having to write `dirname(__FILE__)`.

Answer (score 1):

I've going to take the mathematical approach. PHP always includes additional files from the current *working directory*, not the current file being included.

So if we are in file C (index.php), we are on level 4. File C includes file B which is in the parent directory (according to the `../`) which will be on level 3.

Now file B is *included **inside** file C* (with extra emphasis on inside). We are still working from level 4, not level 3. So when you attempt to include file A, we're technically include file A inside file C, not inside file B, so the path is only going up 3 directories instead of the 4 directories it needs to go up through.

Thus when we are executing file B, which is on level 3, include file A will go up three levels to level 0, which is the appropriate place to look for the file.

I'd suggest using absolute paths to access *all* files because using relative paths only causes problems, such as the one you have found yourself in here.

The way I do it is set a 'root' variable that is accessible throughout all my scripts, for use to define absolute paths. I put it in my index.php file since that is the only file that is ever run.

```
$ani->i->root = dirname(str_replace("\\", "/",  __FILE__));
// Where my $ani variable is accessible everywhere.
```

This way whenever I need to include/require files I can simply do something like `include "{$ani->i->root}/modules/somemodule.php"` and not have to worry about paths, etc.

Comment: That's fine until you move the application to a new location! Relative paths are used to make the app portable to a different location or a different system with a different directory structure.

Comment: Personally I use a single directory for includes and an autoloader, but I don't think he would be open to that.

Comment: @Sinthia If you move the application to a new location, you change one line in the 'config' file.. Which is an acceptable risk if you can avoid include('../../../blah.php') ugliness

Answer (score 0):

Try to use absolute one instead

```
include("/public_html/phpfunctions/generalfunctions.php");
```

Comment: hmmm I'm not sure what you mean: I'm trying this: `include(dirname("/public_html/phpfunctions/generalfunctions.php"));` But it is not working.

Comment: @Jeff: What path does file you're inserting this include code in have?

Comment: you need to use `dirname(__FILE__)` - the constant `__FILE__` contains the filename where it belongs

Comment: @genesis `public_html/plaoul/text/statistics/wordcount.php`

Comment: @genesis: I just explained what you were trying to mean

Answer (score 0):

What happens with include() in php is the function is replaced in the file with the included file. You  are saying with ../wordcount.php that the file can be found in the parent directory of the current working directory. If you get the path correct for file B, php will replace the function in file b with the contents of file a, then replace the include function in file C with file A(after the include).

Edit:oops, my mistake.

Comment: It's not saying it couldn't find wordcount.php, it's saying it couldn't find the file specified on line 11 of wordcount.php, so that file has already been included and is executing.

Comment: OK, so it can't find A, same solution. It is still a path mistake. Move up until you hit the common parent, then go down, starting at the directory your current file is in.