# Parsing folder back, in PHP

Tags: php, directory

Well, it is a litte bit strange, since I remember that if I wan't to go to the directory back, then I need to do the following: `include("../something-in-back-folder.php");` but it throws up an error with message that the file was not found. So I've prepared some code to check this out:

```
echo "<pre>".print_r(scandir("../"), 1)."</pre>";
```

I've executed it in file with location:

`public_html => app => actions => post.php`

but the above code said, that back from my direction there are the following folders:

```
Array
(
    [0] => .
    [1] => ..
    [2] => private_html
    [3] => public_html
)
```

It should return 'actions' folder instead. Right?

Isn't this strange? Or I've missed something? If so, then how can I include/open something that is one(or even two) folders back from my current directorty?

Comment: I answered a similar question two days ago: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7780828/including-files-by-relative-path/7780973#7780973

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct that the `..` notation indicates a reference to the parent folder. Your analysis reveals that your PHP current working directory is at the public_html level; this isn't unusual. Make your reference relative to PHP's current working directory. Assuming you want to get at the 'actions' folder from post.php, say:

```
include('app/actions/something-in-back-folder.php');
```