# Confused with PHP Include

Tags: php

What the different between `./` vs `../` vs `/`

I'm very confused, i tried to access PHP class in different level folder.

I have the following folder structure in `webdir/asia/v1`:

```
+db
  class.database.php
  config.database.php
  +model
    Application.php
text.php
```

In `class.database.php`, I want include `config.database.php` which is in the same folder.

In `Application.php`, I want include `class.database.php` which is in the level above.

In `text.php`, I want include `Application.php`.

How do I include correctly?

What I know for now is that to include files in the same folder, I can use this:

```
include('config.database.php');
```

What about the other two variations? I tried in `Application.php` to include `class.database.php` like this :

```
include_once('../class.database.php');
```

but it doesn't work.

Comment: This is called a relative path. Duplicate question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7780828/including-files-by-relative-path  http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=relative+path+php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use 
include(dirname(dirname(__FILE__)) . "/class.database.php");
and see if it works.

Edit:
Here,dirname(__FILE__) gives you the current directory where dirname of "dirname(__FILE__)" takes you one step up in hierarachy of directory tree.

Comment: if dirname(dirname(__FILE__)) is same with ../../, why use dirname instead ../ ?

Comment: Hi hadi,../../ might work in some cases but this is not the standard way to do it.

Answer (score 3):

`.` is the current directory

`./file.txt` points to a file in the same directory

`..` is the parent directory

`../file.txt` points to a file in the parent directory

`/` is the root directory (like `C:\` on windows)

Comment: i tried use ./somefile.php and it doesn't work, but if i use '/c.php' it work. i'm still confuse

Answer (score 2):

No preceding path means current path, as does `./`.

`../` means up one level.

Answer (score 0):

You can try including the file like this:

`include(dirname(__FILE__) . '/../class.database.php');`

or even using document root from the server:

`include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . 'db/model/Application.php');`