# File Structure for a PHP Project

Tags: php, include, filesystems

My file structure:

```
/holiday/admin/list.php
/holiday/includes/functions.php   # common functions
/holiday/index.php

# / is the document root
# /holiday/ is a "self-contained" sub-directory
# There are other "self-contained" sub-directories e.g. /promotion/, /international/
```

In `functions.php` I have a common function to generate the `<head>` part of an HTML; also, a function to return an absolute path from the document root. **Note** my attempt to calculate `/holiday/includes/`.

```
<? function get_path() {
  // Technically, this returns dirname(__FILE__) - $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']
  return str_replace($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'], "", dirname(__FILE__)); 
} ?>

<? function open_page($head = "", $body_id = "") { ?>
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="<? echo get_path() . "/../css/savvyextras.css"; ?>" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="<? echo get_path() . "/../scripts/modernizr.js"; ?>"></script>
...
<? } ?>
```

`functions.php` is included this way:

```
// From list.php
require_once('../includes/functions.php');
open_page(...);

// From index.php
require_once('./includes/functions.php');
open_page(...);
```

I feel like there must be a more straightforward approach to accomplish the same thing here. Any built-in PHP function for my `get_path()`? Maybe I should approach my problem differently?

**Note:**
Some folks suggested using a framework (which is a good thing). But, to help me (and others) understand this whole include-file thing, other non-framework explanations?

**Related Discussions**:

- [Absolute Path for Deployment in a Non-Root Location](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8123102/absolute-path-for-deployment-in-a-non-root-location)
- [Including files by relative path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7780828/including-files-by-relative-path)

Comment: Given any thought to a framework?  Generally speaking nowadays there are so many strong, mature frameworks that will handle this sort of thing for you in a very easy environment.

Comment: As a side note, you probably  should get rid of the shorttag php notation, meaning, change `<?` to `<?php`.  Shorttag is being deprecated.

Comment: @DeaconDesperado: It's probably differ from dev to dev, but do you have a recommendation of a lightweight framework that does this?

Comment: @Levi: I thought the shorthand is a matter of configuration i.e. short_open_tag?

Comment: This crops up all the time
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3533194/php-short-tags-really-being-deprecated-in-php6
The short tags are staying.  That said, if you may be porting your code to a server with a different, more default config, it may be a good idea to remove them.

Comment: @Siku-Siku.Com - Kohana is great - as is CodeIgniter, the original project kohana sprang from.  Zend is probably overkill generally speaking, if all you need is some method to the madness.  A lightweight MVC like one of the two I mentioned will really change the way you think about your structure and make development SO MUCH easier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After experimenting more with this and gathering other inputs, I find using constant will do the trick:

```
# functions.php

define('PREFIX', '/holiday');

<? function open_page($head = "", $body_id = "") { ?>
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo PREFIX; ?>/css/savvyextras.css"; ?>" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo PREFIX; ?>/scripts/modernizr.js"; ?>"></script>
...
<? } ?>
```

So, if you need to move `/holiday/` to a different sub-directory e.g. `/vacation/`, you'd simply need to change one constant i.e. `PREFIX`.

Comment: In case you need to use the constant inside a heredoc, this discussion should give you an answer: http://stackoverflow.com/q/8242922/583539.

Answer (score 1):

@Siku-Siku.Com, auto-loading classes with __autoload() won't really help your main problem. Besides, you'll only be able to get the most out of __autoload() if you move to a mainly object-oriented design, which will bring its own challenges.

Currently, the most sensible thing to do would be as @hafichuk suggests. Make one main includes file, say my_funcs.inc.php, and include it at the top of every other page you have. The advantage is that by giving special .inc extensions to your include files, you can distinguish them more easily. Plus, you can use that to block these files in Apache for just an added bit of security.

If I could also mention:

1) I think short tags are risky. They encourage bad coding practices and leave the door wide open for porting nightmares. And they encourage bad coding practices.

2) Since require is a statement, not a function, it should be used like:

```
require 'my_file.inc.php';
```

Comment: +1 for the `.inc` suggestion. As you pointed out, I found that `require` typically isn't followed by a `()` although in the PHP documentation, it's considered as a function: http://php.net/manual/en/function.require.php (notice the URL).

Answer (score 0):

With the type of layout that you currently have, your best bet is to have a single `includes.php` file which holds all of your `require_once` calls, then use `require_once('../includes.php')` (or equivalent location) at the top of each of your entry scripts. It's a pain to setup and maintain, but at least it's all in one place.

If you plan on moving towards using objects instead of functions, then I'd take a look at using [`__autoload()`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.autoload.php).

Comment: Note that it wasn't clear if the only require you had was `functions.php`, if that's the case, then there's really no better solution without moving to the `__autoload()` structure

Comment: Thanks, @hafichuk. At this point, yes only 1 file to include, which is `functions.php`. Soon, it'll be more for sure. Are you suggesting that `__autoload()` works best only when there is 1 include file?