# define and heredoc

Tags: php, heredoc

How do you use [define](http://php.net/manual/en/function.define.php) within a [heredoc](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc)? For example:

```
define('PREFIX', '/holiday');

$body = <<<EOD
<img src="PREFIX/images/hello.png" />   // This doesn't work.
EOD;
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

taken from [the documentation regarding strings](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#74744)

```
DEFINE('PREFIX','/holiday');

$const = PREFIX;

echo <<<EOD
<img src="{$const}/images/hello.png" /> 
EOD;
```

Comment: Thanks! Adding a little note: `$const/images/hello.png` will also work.

Comment: curly brackets are not required in this example.

Comment: Also you can use `$consts = get_defined_constants();` to get all define and then access with `{$consts['PREFIX']}`.

Answer (score 7):

if you have more than 1 constant, variable usage would be difficult. so try this method

```
define('PREFIX', '/holiday');
define('SUFFIX', '/work');
define('BLABLA', '/lorem');
define('ETC', '/ipsum');

$cname = 'constant'; // if you want to use a function in heredoc, you must save function name in variable

$body = <<<EOD
<img src="{$cname('PREFIX')}/images/hello.png" />
<img src="{$cname('SUFFIX')}/images/hello.png" />
<img src="{$cname('BLABLA')}/images/hello.png" />
<img src="{$cname('ETC')}/images/hello.png" />
EOD;
```

http://codepad.org/lA8L2wQR

Comment: I followed your suggestion to try that because I thought it is interesting, however it came to my mind that your suggestion looks untested, because it gives many errors.

Comment: (Hmm. Crazy.  I would've never....)  Any thoughts on speed in comparison to @nbonniot answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10041200/interpolate-constant-not-variable-into-heredoc#answer-30777936

Answer (score 3):

> Constants used within the heredoc syntax are not interpreted!
>
> Editor's Note: This is true. PHP has no way of recognizing the
>   constant from any other string of characters within the heredoc block.

[Source](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.constants.php#19363)

Comment: Looks like that there is an exception to that rule: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12508992/367456