# PHP string interpolation syntax

Tags: php

I tried to do redirect with this syntax:

```
header("location: readMore.php?id=$post['post_id']");
```

But it didn't work. It worked only after someone suggested to put curly brackets around `$post['post_id']`!

The correct syntax is:

```
header("location: readMore.php?id={$post['post_id']}");
```

What does the curly brackets do in this case?

Comment: Have you tried to concat like this? `header( "location: readMore.php?id=" . $post[ 'post_id' ] ); `

Comment: no, but i tried now and it does work. But again why my syntax didn't work and these 2 syntax work?

Answer (score 62):

Quoting [the manual](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing):

> When a [string](https://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php) is specified in double quotes or with heredoc, [variables](https://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.php) are parsed within it.
>
> There are two types of syntax: a [simple](https://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing.simple) one and a [complex](https://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing.complex) one. The simple syntax is the most common and convenient. It provides a way to embed a variable, an [array](https://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php) value, or an [object](https://php.net/manual/en/language.types.object.php) property in a [string](https://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php) with a minimum of effort.
>
> The complex syntax can be recognised by the curly braces surrounding the expression.

Your first code uses simple syntax, and your second code uses a complex one.

The manual does not explicitly state this, but whitespace in simple syntax [seems to be an error](https://3v4l.org/Vph24), rendering your first code invalid. Complex syntax *appears* to support the same syntax as regular PHP does as far as I can see, but again this does not seem to be actually guaranteed anywhere.

String interpolation is quite flunky in general:

```
$a = [['derp']];
$b = $a[0];

// Works. It prints derp
echo "$b[0]";

// Doesn't work. It throws an error
echo "$b[ 0 ]";

// Works. It prints derp
echo "{$b[ 0 ]}";

// Doesn't work. It prints Array[0]
echo "$a[0][0]";

// Works. It prints derp
echo "{$a[0][0]}";

// Doesn't work. It prints { Array[0] }
echo "{ $a[0][0] }";
```

You get similar issues with `$object -> foo` and `$object->foo->bar`.

To me, that is pure madness. For that reason I've come to avoid double quoted strings whenever possible (the only thing I used them for are for escape sequences like `"\n"`). I instead use single quotes and string concatenation, like so:

```
header( 'location: readMore.php?id=' . $post[ 'post_id' ] );
```

This lets you use *actual* PHP syntax for variables without the horrible death trap that is string interpolation.

Comment: String interpolation, like all language features, is very useful if you don't abuse it.  I'll take a long interpolated string over a bunch nasty close quotes and dots any day.

Comment: It wouldve all worked nicely if they decided to only allow a single syntax. For instance, this one breaks: `$amount = 500; $str = "I have ${$amount} dollars"`

Comment: This answer says at least three times that interpolation as bad, but never gives a reason why. Obviously whitespace (or any character) where it doesn't belong would cause errors. That is not an example of a language feature being bad, that is an example of you putting characters where they don't belong. If I stuck spaces into the middle of regular, uninterpolated variables, they'd break too.

Comment: @felwithe Not true, `echo $b[ 0 ];` is valid and works just fine, as does `echo     $a[0][0]     ;`. If you want a formal reason why string interpolation is bad, it's because it doesn't align with the entire rest of PHP. The rules are entirely different for no apparent reason.

Comment: In a string whitespace matters. There's no good way for a parser to determine that the characters "{}" contain an expression if they also contain random whitespace or other characters. Unless "{" in a string is to always mean "start expression here"-- but then "{" would have to be escaped any time it appears literally, just like "$".

Comment: @felwithe You gave a justification as to why it is the way it is, but that doesn't make it any less bad. And I'm not saying that I could have built it better either, but that still doesn't mean it's reasonable.

Comment: This answer is entirely subjective and doesn't actually answer the question until a bunch of opinionated editorializing happened.  Like it or don't, the answer to "how do I use string interpolation" doesn't need extraneous opining, especially when stating those opinions as fact: "Stay away from string interpolation. It just goes from bad to worse."

Comment: @Nerdmaster I guess you were right about the first sentence; I removed it. But if you'd like me to see more in your comment than an unsubstantiated rant, would you mind pointing out exactly where I could find that "bunch of opinionated editorializing" you are talking about, how the question is not answered by me pointing out to the OP that curly brackets mean complex string interpolation, and how the quote from the manual or the code that follows are subjective in nature?

Comment: @Siguza: the removal of that first sentence seemed to make all the difference.  The way I read the answer before must have been colored a lot by that one statement, because now I'm not sure why I was so annoyed.  Sorry!

Comment: @felwithe re *"but then "{" would have to be escaped any time it appears literally"* That would have been a cleaner design. Then string interpolation would be simply `{...}` and could handle the cases that it currently fails on: `constants`, `class static variables` that lack `$`, expressions that don't start with `$` e.g. `0-$a`. OR PHP could have defined `${...}` as handling arbitrary expressions, like JavaScript. The parser certainly could have been designed this way, given that [Armfoot's technique](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53734534/199364) is able to wrap arbitrary expressions.

Answer (score 6):

I came to this question to know more about constant interpolation syntax when those PHP "<<<" things are used to create multiline strings called [Heredocs](https://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc) (which allow variable interpolation, unlike [Nowdocs](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.nowdoc)).

However, it seems there is no specific syntax for them, and therefore a simple workaround is to create a closure to do so. In here it is just an anonymous function assigned to a variable that will be invoked with parameters:

```
$int = 'intruder';        // Variable
define('con', '"smart"'); // Constant
// For complex interpolation:
// 1. Define a closure (anonymous function)
// 2. Assign it to a variable with a short name (e.g.: _ )
// 3. Invoke the function by calling the variable with parameters enclosed in ()
$_ = function ($val){return $val;};

$doc = <<<TXT
Hi there,
One day I caught this $int nearby.
I was then told that actually other {$_(con)} $int was there before.
So who came first, the chicken or the egg?
TXT;                      // Heredoc
echo $doc;
```

Output:

> Hi there,
>
> One day I caught this intruder nearby.
>
> I was then told that actually other "smart" intruder was there before.
>
> So who came first, the chicken or the egg?

You can [test the above online on 3v4l](https://3v4l.org/hYTrW). This was based on [this answer with a few more examples with operations inside the interpolation brackets](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39649492/1326147).

Comment: Clever. I've verified that the same technique works inside a double-quoted string!

Answer (score 4):

When you use double or single quotes, PHP will treat whatever is in it as a string unless you tell it that it’s a variable. PHP understands anything after `{`  followed by `$` as a variable and treats it as such. Here is an example:

```
$Text = "XYz";
echo "name-{$Text}";
```

The other alternative method is to use concatenation. Here is an example:

```
header("location: readMore.php?id=" . $post['post_id']);
```

Comment: Bad example, since PHP treats anything inside `echo` contained in double quotes as a variable, if it's prepended with `$` - so this works just fine: `echo "text: $text";`

Answer (score 2):

Brackets allow PHP to read what's inside as a variable. You can do that this way too:

```
header("location: readMore.php?id=" . $post['post_id']);
```

Answer (score 2):

PHP's *simple* string interpolation doesn't recognize quoted array keys, which your example demonstrates perfectly. In fact, the correct way to write this is exactly opposite depending on which syntax used: *simple* vs *complex*.

**Simple syntax - Wrong**

Quoted keys cannot be parsed.

```
header("location: readMore.php?id=$post['post_id']");
```

**Simple syntax - Right**

The unquoted string is the associative array key.

```
header("location: readMore.php?id=$post[post_id]");
```

**Complex syntax - Wrong**

It will work, but only if `post_id` is a defined constant. If not, you'll get a PHP warning.

```
header("location: readMore.php?id={$post[post_id]}");
```

**Complex syntax - Right**

Written just like outside the string.

```
header("location: readMore.php?id={$post['post_id']}");
```

To quote the manual on the [complex syntax](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing.complex):

```
// Works, quoted keys only work using the curly brace syntax
echo "This works: {$arr['key']}";
```

I'd recommend using complex (curly brace) syntax if using quoted keys. And you really should be using them, because outside the string interpolation unquoted keys are actually constants. It's too bad the simple syntax won't allow them, because it makes code reviews and updating old PHP code more difficult.