# Expression evaluation in interpolated strings in PHP

Tags: php, syntax, string-interpolation, expression-evaluation

In JavaScript, you can do this:

```
console.log(`Hello ${3 + 4} World.`)
```

The out put will be `Hello 7 World`. I can do the same in C# with `Console.WriteLine($"Hello {3 + 4} World")`.

In PHP I tried:

```
echo "Hello {3 + 4} World."
```

However the output of this is `Hello {3 + 4} World`.

How do I interpolate expressions in strings in PHP?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PHP string interpolation syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43437121/php-string-interpolation-syntax)

Comment: hm not really unless you are saying it's simply not possible in PHP?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this :
`echo "Hello ".(3+4)." World.";`

Comment: I know I can use that but that is no string interpolation.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to evaluate arbitrary expressions during string interpolation in PHP. You have to either define a variable or use the syntax from John's answer.