# Laravel Multiple data in dynamic $title

Tags: laravel

Laravel how do i pass relationship in title?

This is what I have:

```
  public function show($categoty, $post) {
    $post = Post::where([ ['slug', '=', $post]->firstOrFail();
   $title = $post->category->name;
    return view('home.chords.show', compact('chord', 'title'));
  }
```

This code works... it gets the Category name in title..
My question is how do i pass the post title with the category name?

What I want to show in $title is

*Category Name - Post Title*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [string concatenation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php) like this:

```php
$title = $post->category->name . ' - ' . $post->title;
```

You can also use [string interpolation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43437427/1919845), like this:

```php
$title = "{$post->category->name} - {$post->title}";
```

An other way to achieve this would be to add an accessor in your Post model like this :

```php
// Inside Post Model
public function getCategoryTitleLabelAttribute()
{
    return "{$this->category->name} - {$this->title}";
}

// Anywhere in your app:
$post->category_title_label;
```