# How to use php variables in DOMPDF to generate dynamic PDF?

Tags: php, dompdf, html-to-pdf

Below is my code to generate HTML into PDF using DOMPDF, It will be generating a static pdf up to here perfectly working fine, but when I have added some PHP variables (in the code I am using session variables) to get users' dynamic data that will not render PDF.
Is there any other way to add some dynamic data into the HTML file using DOMPDF before it converts into a final PDF?

```
<?php
//$first_name = "Gopal Kshirsagar" 
session_start();
$_SESSION["mandatory_date"]= $mandatory_date;
$_SESSION["first_name"]= $first_name;
$_SESSION["last_name"]= $last_name;
?>

<?php
use Dompdf\Options;
//add autoload.inc.php
require_once "./dompdf/autoload.inc.php";

// reference the Dompdf namespace
use Dompdf\Dompdf;

// instantiate and use the dompdf class
$dompdf = new Dompdf();

//$dompdf->loadhtml($aData['html']);
$dompdf->set_option('isRemoteEnabled', TRUE);
//$dompdf->loadHtml($html);

$dompdf->loadHtml('
<style> 
   div.background {
      background: #ffffff;
      border: 4px solid black;
      margin: 10px;
    }
    
    div.transbox {
      margin: 3px;
      background-color: #ffffff;
      border: 1px solid black;
    }
    
    div.transbox p {
      margin: 1%;
      color: #000000;
    }
    #middle {
      margin: 5px;
      background-color: #ffffff;
      border: 1px solid #fff;
    }
    body{
       background-color: #f6f6f6;
    }
    .logowhite{
     float: right;
    }
    .logo {
       clear: right;
       text-align: center;
   }
      </style>
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>
   <link href="https://vip-organon-us-hcp-com-develop.go-vip.net/nexplanontraining/wp-content/themes/twentytwentyone-child/assets/css/main.min2.css" media="all" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet"/>         
   <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
   <body id="thank-you" class="base"><div id="middle">
   <div class="background">
      <div class="transbox">
         <!----Below Images I have embedded and convert into base64 (using online converter https://base64.guru/converter/encode/image)-->
         <div  class="logowhite"> <img alt="" src="org_logo.jpg" /></div> 
         <div class="logo"> <img src="nexplanon.jpg" alt="" />  
           <p style="font-size:1.35rem;color:#00F;text-transform: uppercase;"><?php echo $first_name; ?> &nbsp; <?php echo $last_name; ?></p> 
           <p style="font-size: 1.25rem;line-height:25px;">This certificate serves as confirmation of the completion of the Mandatory Training Module<BR>
             on the updated insertion and removal procedures for NEXPLANON.</p> 
            
             <div style="width: 70%;margin: auto;"> 
               <p style="float: left;font-size: 1.25rem;"><B>Training Date:</B> <span style="color: #00F;"><?php echo $mandatory_date; ?></span> </p>
               <img style="float:right;" alt="" src="sign.jpg" />   </div>
           
           </div>
           <div style="width: 90%;margin: auto;"> 
            <p style="clear: both;margin-bottom: 0%;line-height:18px;"><BR>I attested that I completed the Organon-sponsored Mandatory Training Module on the updated insertion and removal procedures for NEXPLANON in its entirety. I understand that only healthcare providers who have completed the
            Organon-sponsored Clinical Training Program for NEXPLANON may order, insert, and remove NEXPLANON.<BR><BR>
            I certified that I am authorized to perform the procedures entailed in the insertion and removal of NEXPLANON in the
            jurisdiction where I practice. I attest that if there are specific state requirements in the state where I practice, I have met all appropriate state conditions including but not limited to collaborative or signing agreement with an MD/DO.<BR><BR>
            If I am a resident or student in advanced practice training, I understand that I should only administer NEXPLANON under the supervision of an attending healthcare provider who has also been trained on the procedures to insert and
            remove NEXPLANON.</p>
         </div><br/>
     
      <div style="padding-bottom: -2%;">
      <p style="font-size: 0.7rem;float: left;">© 2021 Organon group of companies. All rights reserved. ORGANON and the ORGANON Logo are trademarks of the Organon group of companies.</p>
      <p style="float: right;font-size: 0.7rem;">US-XPL-115639 12/21</p>
     <p style="clear: both;margin-bottom: 0%;"> </p>
     </div>
      
     
     </div>
   </div>
   </div></body>
');


// (Optional) Setup the paper size and orientation
$dompdf->setPaper('A4', 'landscape');

// Render the HTML as PDF
$dompdf->render();

// Output the generated PDF to Browser
$dompdf->stream("training-certificate", array("Attachments"=>0));
?>
```

Comment: You are looking for either string interpolation or just concatenation. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43437121/231316) or [the manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php). While doing this, completely ignore PDF for starters, just test getting the HTML built.

Comment: You will need to refactor the string lines within `' ... '` to end the string and concatenate with the variable before starting the string again `'string'  . $var . 'string'`.  Example of : `<p style="font-size:1.35rem;color:#00F;text-transform: uppercase;">' . $first_name . ' &nbsp; ' . $last_name . '</p>`

Comment: Alternatively, copy the HTML code excluding the single quotes `'` to a separate PHP file and use a output buffering and `include` to save the processed data to a variable to pass to `loadHtml()`. Example: `ob_start(); include __DIR__ . '/template.php'; $html = ob_get_clean(); $dompdf->loadHtml($html);`

Comment: @Will B, Thank you so much, given html->php concatenation works <p style="font-size:1.35rem;color:#00F;text-transform: uppercase;">' . $first_name . ' &nbsp; ' . $last_name . '</p>

Comment: The same session variable I used in our server (testing environment), It's not working in that particular custom PHP page that generates pdf. I am using those session variables on localhost It's working fine then why those are not working on the server?