# How to use PHP variables in a Graphql query?

Tags: php, graphql

This is using WPGraphql with WordPress but I believe it's a general PHP and/or Graphql issue. I've been searching for 2 days now, and everything I've found is specific to some library or framework or otherwise not helpful. Any help with this is super appreciated.

The code below creates a variable $post_slug which contains the slug of the current post.

If I replace id: $post_slug with an actual post slug (id: "my-groovy-post") it works, but apparently $post_slug is undefined within the query.

```
<?php

$post_slug = get_post_field( 'post_name', get_post() );

$graphql = graphql([
    'query' => ' {
  post(idType: SLUG, id: $post_slug) {
    title
    content
    date
  }
}'
]);


echo '<pre>';
var_dump($graphql);
echo '</pre>';
?>
```

The results of my query

```
array(2) {
  ["errors"]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    array(3) {
      ["message"]=>
      string(37) "Variable "$post_slug" is not defined."
      ["extensions"]=>
      array(1) {
        ["category"]=>
        string(7) "graphql"
      }
      ["locations"]=>
      array(2) {
        [0]=>
        array(2) {
          ["line"]=>
          int(2)
          ["column"]=>
          int(27)
        }
        [1]=>
        array(2) {
          ["line"]=>
          int(1)
          ["column"]=>
          int(2)
        }
      }
    }
  }
  ["extensions"]=>
  array(1) {
    ["debug"]=>
    array(1) {
      [0]=>
      array(2) {
        ["type"]=>
        string(19) "DEBUG_LOGS_INACTIVE"
        ["message"]=>
        string(86) "GraphQL Debug logging is not active. To see debug logs, GRAPHQL_DEBUG must be enabled."
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Double-quote your string if you expect $post_slug to be interpolated within it.

Comment: Reference: [PHP string interpolation syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43437121/php-string-interpolation-syntax)

Comment: Thanks ADyson but no luck. Double quotes removes the part about $post_slug being undefined but then returns a null result.

Comment: Well that sorts the error you asked about. Why you get no results is another matter

Comment: That doesn't sort anything. I asked about the variable being undefined, not how to hide it. From what I gather, it's undefined because I'm using it in the graphql() function provided by WPGraphql, which accepts an array. That means I have to use global $post_slug inside the function, which calls for an array of args. That's the part I don't know how to do. Here's the function from the WPGraphql plugin -- `function graphql( $request_data = [] ) {
 $request = new \WPGraphQL\Request( $request_data );

 return $request->execute();
}
`

Comment: I didn't suggest to hide anything - not sure what you mean by that? Let me check my assumptions in case I misunderstood. 1) `$post_slug` is a variable in your PHP - we can see that - which contains a string value of some sort (as per https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_post_field/). 2) You want to include this variable in the string you're putting into the array which you're passing into the grapql() function. So it's simple, double-quoting the string allows the variable in that string to be parsed, instead of being treated as raw text

Comment: i.e. let's say `$post_slug` has the value "xyz". That means your query string would become `{
  post(idType: SLUG, id: xyz) {
    title
    content
    date
  }
}` (instead of staying as the raw `{
  post(idType: SLUG, id: $post_slug) {
    title
    content
    date
  }
}` which it would be if you single-quoted the string. Demo: https://3v4l.org/hbalt . Is that not what you wanted? Of course I can't comment on whether that would create a valid graphql which would actually return results from your particular data store.

Comment: @ADyson Thank you for all your effort. 
_"2) You want to include this variable in the string you're putting into the array..."_ 
Exactly. Problem is I have to do it within the graphql() function, which won't let me use double quotes in that way. I tried just double quoting the variable `id: "$post_slug"` but that just turns it into a string. If I type a valid post slug `id: "my-groovy-post"` for example, it works. So I know the query is correct. Just don't know how to get that variable in there.

Comment: `Problem is I have to do it within the graphql() function, which won't let me use double quotes in that way`...again, not sure what you mean? 1) you're not doing it within the graphql function, you're doing it within an array which you're declaring and then passing into that function. So the string-building and _interpolation_ is happening before you pass anything to the function. It's standard PHP syntax and functionality, nothing to do with graphql. 2) `I tried just double quoting the variable`...but that's not what I suggested...did you look at the demo? Or the link I posted last night?

Comment: Yes, after seeing your demo I tried it that way. You can see in my code the query is done within the graphql() function. Your query is in a print_r() function, where it works. It doesn't work in the graphql() function, just breaks the code and throws an error `["message"]=>
      string(57) "Syntax Error: Invalid number, expected digit but got: "p""`

Comment: Well my bit works in the sense of interpolating the variable properly. The problem you seem to have now is that graphQL expected a numeric value, but your $post_slug value contains `p` instead. So I don't really know graphQL but I can use google, and it seems it wants you to quote the field so it can be treated as a string in the context of the graphQL query. So you can add escaped quote marks, like this: https://3v4l.org/XY9SG . Or you go back to single-quoted PHP string, add the quote marks verbatim and concatenate the slug value, like this: https://3v4l.org/suI5r . Same result either way

Comment: Yay! That did the trick. Thank you so much, you're awesome!

Answer (score 1):

Thank you to @ADyson for his persistence in figuring this out. The solution was twofold -- first wrap the query in double quotes for interpolation, then wrap the variable in escaped double quotes. Here's the updated code...

```
<?php
$post_slug = get_post_field( 'post_name', get_post() );

$graphql = graphql([
    'query' => "{
  post(idType: SLUG, id: \"$post_slug\") {
    title
    content
    date
  }
}"
]);

echo '<pre>';
var_dump($graphql);
echo '</pre>';
?>
```