# PHP base64_encode variables inside a string

Tags: php

I have created the following PHP code long time ago and it works, but I don't understand, why base64_encode is working with 2 variables, which are put together, inside a string `base64_encode("$user:$pass")`?

I hope somebody can help me to understand it.

Here the complete code section:

```
    $user  = "username";
    $pass= "password";

    //HTTP options
    $opts = array('http' =>
        array(
            'method'    => 'GET',
            'header'    => array ('Authorization: Basic '.base64_encode("$user:$pass"))
        )
    );

    //Do request
    $context = stream_context_create($opts); // creates GET request with encoded password 
    $url = "http://www.myURL.com/subpage";
    $list = file_get_contents($url, false, $context); // get xml info
```

Comment: `"$user:$pass"` is the same as `$user . ':' . $pass`.

Answer (score 1):

You're not passing 2 variables into the base64 function.

The two variables are contained within a single static string. When the code runs, the variables are interpolated to their real values to form the completed string, and then *after that* it's passed into the function.

If it helps to break it down, the code is equivalent to:

```
$credentials = "$user:$pass";
base64_encode($credentials);
```

which is equivalent to

```
$credentials = $user.":".$pass;
base64_encode($credentials);
```

[PHP string interpolation syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43437121/php-string-interpolation-syntax) might be helpful background reading.