# Can I combine two string variables in PHP with just writing them next to each other like "$variable1$variable2"?

Tags: php

I'm returning a page slug created with two string variables like this in PHP:

```
$result = $site_url . '/' . $final_slug;
return $result;
```

But I've noticed that someone online did it like this:

```
return "$site_url/$final_slug";
```

Is the second version valid too, because it seems to work in my code?

Comment: Yes, as your attempts surely showed yourself.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the difference between single-quoted and double-quoted strings in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3446216/what-is-the-difference-between-single-quoted-and-double-quoted-strings-in-php)

Comment: [PHP string interpolation syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43437427)

Comment: If you use double quotes for a string, then the **$** is interpreted and variables are expanded.  For instance "$var1$var2" is also perfectly valid.