# How do I insert a php variable inside javascript inside PHP

Tags: javascript, php

I used:
`function redirect($url) {header('Location: '.$url); exit(); }`
on my local network server without any problems but it failed with 'output already sent' errors on my hosting server. I devised a javascript work-around that works as shown in the code below.

```
`function redirect_to($new_location)
    {
        $redirects = [
            "<script>window.location.replace(\"login.php\");</script>",
            "<script>window.location.replace(\"select_set.php\");</script>",
            "<script>window.location.replace(\"run_order.php\");</script>",
            "<script>window.location.replace(\"display_setlist.php\");</script>",
            "<script>window.location.replace(\"manage_admins.php\");</script>",
            "<script>window.location.replace(\"clients.php\");</script>",
            "<script>window.location.replace(\"manage_songs.php\");</script>",
            "<script>window.location.replace(\"admin.php\");</script>"
        ];
        for ($i=0;$i<count($redirects);$i++) {
            if (strpos($redirects[$i], $new_location)) {
                echo $redirects[$i];
            }
        }
    }`
```

It's not elegant and requires a separate script to be written for each redirect.

My question: Is there a way to insert the PHP variable '$new_location' into the javascript string. Can it be done?

I learned how to insert javascript into php and vice versa. I've tried combining the two insertion methods in various ways without success.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PHP string interpolation syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43437121/php-string-interpolation-syntax)

Comment: PHP is server side. Javascript is client side. What you need to remember is that PHP will _always_ execute _before_ any output is sent to the browser. That means that by the time your website is showing up, PHP has already done its job. If your PHP needs information from Javascript, you need to use Ajax (or something similar, like a websocket) so you can transmit that information to your PHP backend after the website has loaded.

Comment: _"but it failed with 'output already sent' errors on my hosting server"_ - Wouldn't it be better to solve that issue instead of creating a, as you said it, "not elegant" workaround? Just make sure you always call `header()` in PHP before _any output what so ever_, and it should work.

Comment: Thank you ice cub. I do get confused. I should mention that the 'PHP header' function did work for some redirects but not others. The javascript solution works for all.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You really should use .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ /$1.php [L,R=301]
```

A lookup and header redirect should work and you should investigate why it does not work.

You likely inserted whitespace like

```
?>

<?php
```

Here is a version you can use once you figured out what is going on on the hosting. Their helpdesk should be able to help.

```
function redirect_to($new_location) {
  $redirects = [
    'login' => 'login.php',
    'select_set' => 'select_set.php',
    'run_order' => 'run_order.php',
    'display_setlist' => 'display_setlist.php',
    'manage_admins' => 'manage_admins.php',
    'clients' => 'clients.php',
    'manage_songs' => 'manage_songs.php',
    'admin' => 'admin.php'
  ];

  if(array_key_exists($new_location, $redirects)) {
    header('Location: ' . $redirects[$new_location]);
    exit;
  }
}
```

Comment: The question says they already tried the second approach, and what happened when they did.

Comment: They likely added whitespace somewhere before the redirect header line

Comment: Thank you @mplungjan I will look into '.htaccess'. I have no experience of that.

Comment: First look at the code you had before you added the JS. I think you have a whitespace somewhere it does not belong.

Comment: I think I accepted @mplungjan answer although the page shows -1 which seems unfair. I restored the 'php header' function without any spaces and it looks like it's all working.

Comment: @SteveMessenger Some other user downvoted my initial post, which I wrote before I realised you already had tried that.