# How to get differance in hours and minutes between tow timestamp in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

this is my attendance table
[image]

i need to get differance between check in and check out in hours and minutes and seconeds formate
this my controller

```
        $checkin=DB::table('attendances')->where('id',6)->get('checkin');
        $checkout=DB::table('attendances')->where('id',6)->get('checkout');
        $originalTime = date_create('$checkin');
        $targedTime = date_create('$checkout');
        $interval = date_diff($originalTime,$targedTime);
        dd($interval->format("%H:%I:%S"));
```

but i get following error
[image]

Comment: looks like your problem is you added `'` on your `date_create`, making it into a simple string, rather than your time variants. Change to `$originalTime = date_create($checkin);` and for `$targedTime` as well

Comment: I cannot imagine why you decided it was a good idea to store dates in what appears to be a varchar field in your database. `DATETIME` exists for a reason - use it!!

Comment: But yeah your issue is that single-quoted strings are not interpolated (see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43437121/php-string-interpolation-syntax and elsewhere). Therefore you end up passing the literal text "$checkin" to date_create. There' s no need to surround something which is already a string with quote marks, anyway!

Comment: i tried this
$originalTime = date_create($checkin);
but still same error

Comment: Well, what value were you using for `$checkin` when you get that error? Presumably it's not a valid parseable date. As per the PHP documentation, date_create returns `false` if it can't create a date object from the value you pass in. The possible valid date formats you can pass in are also shown in the PHP documentation. So...what investigation have you done? There should be no need to be puzzled about it. Check whether the value you're providing to the function is a valid one or not.

Comment: i get $checkin as object type

  "checkin": "Thu 07-09-2023 10:45:26 am"

Comment: Well an object is not a string! Extract the actual date string itself from that, and pass it to date_create, and your code will work - demo: https://3v4l.org/akPqg

Comment: so how to extract actual date string

Comment: I don't really know. You showed what seems to be a JSON representation of the object. But I'm not sure if that's it's underlying structure. If you put `var_dump($checkin);` what does it output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are having issues because you didn't created `$originalTime` correctly. `date_create()` function needs a datetime variable, if you add ' char, it will be interpreted as a string. Thats why `$originalTime` is a boolean, not a datetime variable.

Also, you saved datetime as string in database. So you should remove the ' and convert string to datetime;

```
    $checkin=DB::table('attendances')->where('id',6)->get('checkin');
    $checkout=DB::table('attendances')->where('id',6)->get('checkout');
    $originalTime = date_create(strtotime($checkin));
    $targedTime = date_create(strtotime($checkout));
    $interval = date_diff($originalTime,$targedTime);
    dd($interval->format("%H:%I:%S"));
```

I also recommend keeping the datetime information as datetime in the database. In this way, you can make the transaction much easier and hassle-free.